# PHP push objects to array from foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have set up a post CURL request where I'm receiving data from the front end and then formatting it a format which another third-party API can receive.

I'm struggling with how I can add some dynamic product data to the main array list via a foreach loop, as it's a post request it's fairly hard to debug, I just get a cors error back on the front end.

```
$data = array(
        'TradingName'=>'Olivias',
        'OrderNumber'=>$_POST['OrderNumber'],
        'OrderReference'=>$_POST['OrderReference'],
        'Recipient'=>$_POST['Recipient'],
        'Address'=>$_POST['Address'],
        'Postcode'=>$_POST['Postcode'],
        'ContactHome'=>$_POST['ContactHome'],
        'ContactWork'=>$_POST['ContactWork'],
        'ContactMobile'=>$_POST['ContactMobile'],
        'ContactEmail'=>$_POST['ContactEmail'],
        'Charge'=>$_POST['Charge'],
        'DeliveryInstructions'=>$_POST['DeliveryInstructions'],
        'OtherInstructions'=>$_POST['OtherInstructions'],
        'TimedService'=>$_POST['TimedService'],
        'ServiceType'=>$_POST['ServiceType'],
        'ServiceLevel'=>$_POST['ServiceLevel'],
        'DeliveryPoint'=>$_POST['DeliveryPoint'],
        'UnpackItems'=>$_POST['UnpackItems'],
        'TakePackagingAway'=>$_POST['TakePackagingAway'],
        'Assemble'=>$_POST['Assemble'],
        'Disassemble'=>$_POST['Disassemble'],
        'CollectDisposal'=>$_POST['CollectDisposal'],       
    );
    

    
    foreach($_POST['fulfillmentItems'] as $i => $item){
            array_push($data, (object)[
                'Action_'.$i+1=>,'Deliver',
                'QTY_'.$i+1=>1,
                'Code_'.$i+1=>$item[$i]['sku'],
                'Description_'.$i+1=>$item[$i]['description'],
                'Parts_'.$i+1=>1,
                'Weight_'.$i+1=>$item[$i]['weight'],
                'Cube_'.$i+1=>1,
            ]);
        }
```

I'm just trying to add that bottom list to the top one, e.g Action_1 ...... Action_2...

Here's an example :-

```
'Recipient'=>'Joe Smith',
'Address'=>'2 Paramo House, Darlington',
'Postcode'=>'DL3 0LP',
'ContactHome'=>'',
'ContactWork'=>'01325 952050',
'ContactMobile'=>'',
'ContactEmail'=>'support@gsit.co.uk',
'Charge'=>32.50,
'DeliveryInstructions'=>'Leave in Porch',
'OtherInstructions'=>'Customer hard of hearing',
'TimedService'=>'All Day',
'ServiceType'=>'Standard',
'ServiceLevel'=>'2 Man',
'DeliveryPoint'=>'Room Of Choice',
'UnpackItems'=>'',
'TakePackagingAway'=>'',
'Assemble'=>'',
'Disassemble'=>'',
'CollectDisposal'=>'',
'Action_1'=>'Deliver',
'QTY_1'=>1,
'Code_1'=>'HG00023',
'Description_1'=>'Silver Birch Bed Frame',
'Parts_1'=>3,
'Weight_1'=>23,
'Cube_1'=>1,
'Action_2'=>'Collect',
'QTY_2'=>1,
'Code_2'=>'HG00023',
'Description_2'=>'Silver Birch Bed Frame (damaged)',
'Parts_2'=>3,
'Weight_2'=>23,
'Cube_2'=>1
```

Comment: CORS error is nothing to do with the code yo show here

Comment: Can you come up with an example of how you want the `$data` array to look after you have added things to it please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I believe the cors error is just because the PHP breaks before the relevant headers are added. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to push an _object_ onto the array? It looks like you simply need to add key-value pairs on the top level, no nesting or anything. `$data['Action_'.$i+1] = 'Deliver';`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then as per your desired result example, you need to do this in the foreach loop not a `array_push()`

```
$data = array(
        'TradingName'=>'Olivias',
        'OrderNumber'=>$_POST['OrderNumber'],
        'OrderReference'=>$_POST['OrderReference'],
        'Recipient'=>$_POST['Recipient'],
        'Address'=>$_POST['Address'],
        'Postcode'=>$_POST['Postcode'],
        'ContactHome'=>$_POST['ContactHome'],
        'ContactWork'=>$_POST['ContactWork'],
        'ContactMobile'=>$_POST['ContactMobile'],
        'ContactEmail'=>$_POST['ContactEmail'],
        'Charge'=>$_POST['Charge'],
        'DeliveryInstructions'=>$_POST['DeliveryInstructions'],
        'OtherInstructions'=>$_POST['OtherInstructions'],
        'TimedService'=>$_POST['TimedService'],
        'ServiceType'=>$_POST['ServiceType'],
        'ServiceLevel'=>$_POST['ServiceLevel'],
        'DeliveryPoint'=>$_POST['DeliveryPoint'],
        'UnpackItems'=>$_POST['UnpackItems'],
        'TakePackagingAway'=>$_POST['TakePackagingAway'],
        'Assemble'=>$_POST['Assemble'],
        'Disassemble'=>$_POST['Disassemble'],
        'CollectDisposal'=>$_POST['CollectDisposal'],       
    );
    
foreach($_POST['fulfillmentItems'] as $i => $item){
    $data['Action_'.$i+1]       = 'Deliver';
    $data['QTY_'.$i+1]          = 1;
    $data['Code_'.$i+1]         = $item['sku'];
    $data['Description_'.$i+1]  = $item['description'];
    $data['Parts_'.$i+1]        = 1;
    $data['Weight_'.$i+1]       = $item['weight'];
    $data['Cube_'.$i+1]          = 1;
            
}
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: But how would I add the results of the foreach to the $data array above?

Comment: This would add these to the `$data` array above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make just 1 array out of 2 arrays, you can simply do `array_merge($array1, $array2)`

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

this will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
    [3] => yellow
)
```

its way faster then array_push, that will read the entire list before pushing one element to the end.